# WP Job manager Location dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im using the WP Job Manager plug on my website. On the home page im using the Hero search filter that has the location search input, that is a text input at the moment but I would like to change it to a dropdown with set options. I've been able to easily change the location text input to a dropdown with the chosen options. 
I hit search, nothing changes in the job listings below.

I've tried to change the way the input is handled in the source files but with no luck. When i output the result of the 'Location' input on the job listing page but it keeps coming back as an empty field.

I have no idea what els to try to accomplish the desired result any more so any help or input would be appreciated.

The code below is how my **part-job-filters.php** code.

```
    <?php
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Job_Manager' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $keywords          = '';
    $location          = array();
    $selected_category = array();

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['search_keywords'] ) ) {
        $keywords = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['search_keywords'] );
    }
    // Old Location input field
    // if ( ! empty( $_GET['search_location'] ) ) {
    //  $location = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['search_location'] );
    // }

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['search_location'] ) ) {
        $location = absint( $_GET['search_location'] );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['search_category'] ) ) {
        if ( is_array( $_GET['search_category'] ) ) {
            $selected_category = absint( reset( $_GET['search_category'] ) );
        } else {
            $selected_category = absint( $_GET['search_category'] );
        }
        $_GET['search_category'] = $selected_category;
    }

    if ( is_tax( 'job_listing_category' ) ) {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $_GET['search_category'] = $selected_category = array( $term->term_id );
    }

?>


<div class="form-filter">
    <div class="form-filter-header">
        <a href="#" class="form-filter-dismiss">&times;<span class="sr-only"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Dismiss filters', 'specialty' ); ?></span></a>
    </div>

    <?php
        $has_categories = true;
        $count = wp_count_terms( 'job_listing_category', array(
            'hide_empty' => 1, // Hide empty, as they are not displayed by the dropdown anyway.
        ) );
        if ( is_wp_error( $count ) || 0 === intval( $count ) || is_tax( 'job_listing_category' ) ) {
            $has_categories = false;
        }

        $col_classes = array(
            'keywords' => 'col-lg-3 col-xs-12',
            'location'    => 'col-lg-3 col-xs-12',
            'category'    => 'col-lg-3 col-xs-12',
            'button'      => 'col-lg-3 col-xs-12',
        );

        if ( ! get_option( 'job_manager_enable_categories' ) || ! $has_categories ) {
            $col_classes = array(
                'keywords' => 'col-lg-4 col-xs-12',
                'location'    => 'col-lg-4 col-xs-12',
                'category'    => '',
                'button'      => 'col-lg-3 push-lg-1 col-xs-12',
            );
        }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $col_classes['keywords'] ); ?>">
                <label for="job-keywords" class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e( 'Job Keywords', 'specialty' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" id="job-keywords" name="search_keywords" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Keywords', 'specialty' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $keywords ); ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $col_classes['location'] ); ?>">
                <label for="job-location" class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e( 'Job Location', 'specialty' ); ?></label>
                <div class="ci-select">

                    <select name="search_location" id="job-location" data-no_results_text="No results match" data-multiple_text="Select Some Options">
                            <option value="0">Select a location</option>
                            <option value="Eastern Cape">Eastern Cape</option>
                            <option value="Free State">Free State</option>
                            <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
                            <option value="kwazulu natal">kwazulu natal</option>
                            <option value="Limpopo">Limpopo</option>
                            <option value="Mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
                            <option value="North West">North West</option>
                            <option value="Northern Cape">Northern Cape</option>
                            <option value="Western Cape">Western Cape</option>
                            <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
                            <option value="International">International</option>
                            <option value="All locations">All locations</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>


            <?php if ( get_option( 'job_manager_enable_categories' ) && $has_categories ) : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $col_classes['category'] ); ?>">
                    <label for="job-category" class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e( 'Job Category', 'specialty' ); ?></label>
                    <div class="ci-select">
                        <?php
                            $multiple = get_option( 'job_manager_enable_default_category_multiselect' );

                            job_manager_dropdown_categories( array(
                                'taxonomy'        => 'job_listing_category',
                                'hierarchical'    => 1,
                                'show_option_all' => $multiple ? false : esc_html__( 'Any category', 'specialty' ),
                                'name'            => 'search_category',
                                'orderby'         => 'name',
                                'selected'        => $selected_category,
                                'multiple'        => $multiple,
                            ) );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $col_classes['button'] ); ?>">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-jobs-filter" type="submit"><?php esc_html_e( 'Search', 'specialty' ); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I might be approaching this the wrong way, if so please could someone advise what the right way is of approaching this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace id in select element, id="job-location" to id="search_location".